# Proper way to add an int to a size_t

Tags: c++

I get the Clang warning "implicit conversion changes signedness" about the following code:

```
size_t x = 10;
int y = -1;
x += y;
```

`x` is an index to a std::vector, so it makes sense that it should be an unsigned long long (a.k.a. size_t), but `y` is an offset that may be positive or negative, and thus needs to be signed. I can cast `y` to a size_t which silences the warning and produces the correct result, however this doesn't seem correct because the cast-to value is definitely not equal to -1 anymore. So, is there a proper way to add a negative number to a size_t?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jtmgbB

Comment: You could save yourself all of the hassle and switch to using `ptrdiff_t` instead of `size_t` for the index.  Yes, you lose 1 bit a values, but 63 bits of index is still a lot.

Comment: @NathanOliver that wouldn't be right, since `std::vector` wants `size_t` for indexing.

Comment: @SergeyA: Actually std::vector wants std::vector::size_type for indexing. Let's be sensible, use ptrdiff_t for this, pretty please, with sugar on top.

Comment: @Bathsheba which is `size_t`. The point I am making that if the compiler is so uptight regarding signed to unsigned conversions (which I could not reproduce so far!) I'd expect it to be equally uptight when you use signed value when unsigned is expected.

Comment: Just don't compile with `-Wsign-conversion`, and add the signed number that gets converted, because `((size_t) 10) + ((size_t) -1) == (size_t) 9`.

Comment: @SergeyA: Which *might* be `size_t`. Point I'm trying to make is that using `ptrdiff_t` is no worse really than using `size_t`.

Comment: Don't assume that `size_t` is `unsigned long long`. `size_t` is defined as some implementation-defined unsigned integer type. It's either `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` on the implementations I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this doesn't seem correct because the cast-to value is definitely not equal to -1 anymore.

As far as the result of the addition is concerned, it doesn't matter that it is no longer -1. It is still congruent with -1 modulo M <sup>1</sup>, so the unsigned addition has the correct result.

<sup>1</sup> M is number of representable values.

> So, is there a proper way to add a negative number to a size_t?

You can do exactly what is done in the example. It is proper.

If you wanted to keep the warning enabled, and wanted to silence it, then you could do the explicit conversion. But this is actually more error prone, since if you accidentally convert to a wrong unsigned type (which may happen due to refactoring), the assumption above no longer holds. For this reason, you should also avoid storing the converted unsigned value in an intermediary variable. I recommend that you don't enable the warning option in question.

---

As discussed in the comments, since you're using `size_t`, you may want to consider using `ptrdiff_t` as the offset type so that you can have offset to any index.

Even more appropriate since you're indexing `vector` would be to use `vector::size_type` and `vector::difference_type` although in practice they are likely to be the same as `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: *"explicit conversion ... more error prone ... don't enable the warning"* Alternatively, something like `x += decltype(x)(y);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I guess that would work. I wouldn't let it touch my code base though :)